# Wordpress returns unfound file only when cacheing enabled

Tags: php, wordpress

Seems like a simple problem, but I can't find an answer.

With cacheing disabled, everything works fine.
With cacheing enabled the following javascript include returns a Wordpress 'page unfound' error.

http://myserver/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js

I'm disabling the cache using the Firefox web developer tool, but I can't see that that should have any bearing in the issue. For some reason, Wordpress can't find a legit file.

The script is properly registered and queued with the following code:

```
 wp_register_script("jquery.cycle.all.min.js", $plugin_url . '/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', 'jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script("jquery.cycle.all.min.js");
```

Comment: What kind of caching are you doing?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas It's just regular browser caching that causes the problem. The website itself (just a development instance) isn't cached server side at all.

Comment: You say Wordpress can't find the file, but you're talking about client-side caching. Who isn't finding the file, Wordpress or your browser? Are you seeing any error messages? If it's a browser issue, you should check out [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s "Net" tab to see if the file in question is being downloaded when you reload the page.

Comment: @AndrésGattinoni You've got it. If cacheing was enabled, the browser 'displayed' a cached version of Wordpress's file not found page. Oddly, when cacheing was disabled, the browser got the correct file, but the cached version was left and used again when cacheing was enabled again. Obvious when you think about it, but I've never seen (or noticed) that behaviour before. All that was required was a cache clear. I owe you 50 points ... I think if you enter 'clear the browser cache' as an answer I can assign them ...

Comment: You know you have a Wordpress StackExchange right? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I read this a little late, but never mind the points, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does turning your cache back on make the problem come back? If not, then it was a problem with your browser's cache, not the server. If the problem *does* return then you should look at the headers, as Samuel Edwin Ward mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Clear browser cache. (dur ... I know).

Unexpected behaviour when switching browser cache on and off, with files that were kept in the cache for a long time.

Comment: It would probably also be a good idea to look at what headers the web server is sending that are causing the error to be cached so long, and perhaps modify them.